# How do I check if a textfield in iframe is empty?

Tags: javascript, iframe, textfield

Pretty much the question sums it up. I'm trying to do something similar to Gmail, where if you've entered stuff in a text field then the website will prompt you to to confirm if you want to leave the page.

But what if the text field in question is in an iframe? Obviously I can assign the iframe an id, but is there any javascript command or something that can check if a field in an iframe is empty or not? Is this even possible?

**Edit:** The iframe source and page the iframe is embedded in are from the same domain.

Comment: Please comment if page and IFrame are on the same domain or not. Side note: no need for signature in the question...

Comment: My bad about the signature. Yes, the iframe and page are on the same domain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var value = document.getElementById('iframeID').contentDocument
                    .getElementById('theTextBoxId').value;
```

And yes, it's possible, you just need to get access to the `<iframe>` document with `contentDocument`.

> From the DOM iframe element, scripts can get access to the window object of the included HTML page via the contentWindow property. The contentDocument property refers to the document element inside the iframe (this is equivalent to contentWindow.document), but is not supported by Internet Explorer versions before IE8.
>
> **Scripts trying to access a frame's content are subject to the same-origin policy**, and cannot access most of the properties in the other window object if it was loaded from a different domain.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting)

Comment: +1. Note that such code only works when page and content of IFrame come from same domain.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, thanks, I added it to the answer for next visitors though the OP wrote that for his specific case he doesn't have that problem.

Comment: Thanks, this was the best answer to the question. I think Kolink's proposal is better suited for my situation though. I hadn't thought to do that before.

Answer (score 1):

Just set `onbeforeunload` as you would as if the iframe'd page were the top-level page. If you try to navigate away in the parent frame or the child frame, it will be interrupted by the confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery you can access the iframe content:

```
$("#iFrame").contents().find("#text")
```